# Encounter error when there is if else in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am new in mvc and trying to learn.i want to display a form when ViewBag.Success is null or empty but if ViewBag.Success is true then i want to render a partial view.

### here is my code

```
<div id="mydiv">
    @if (ViewBag.Success != null && ViewBag.Success == true) //Show the message
    { 
        Html.RenderPartial("Message"); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Game", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "Form1" }))
        {
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="name" type="text" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Salary :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="salary" type="text" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    }
</div>
```

the error message i am getting when i am running like
**Expected a "{" but found a "/".  Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}".  You cannot use single-statement control-flow statements in CSHTML pages. For example, the following is not allowed:**

what i am doing wrong not being able to understand. please help & guide. thanks

Comment: when i remove @ sign from using & // character from code then it started works. why @ sign causes error ? can u anyone guide. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` symbol is only required when your code is contained within an HTML element. The `using` statement does not need the `@` because it is a direct decedent of your if else block.

Example:

```
<div> <!-- html tag -->
    @if(something == somethingElse) // requires @ because direct decedent of html tag <div>
    {
    <p>
        @for (var i=0; i < len; i++) // requires @ because direct decedent of html tag <p>
        {
        if(i == 1) // doesnt require @, not decedent of any HTML tag, instead direct decedent of another razor statement (for)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    </p>
    }
</div>
```

The `@` sign is use to distinguish between a simple string / HTML and razor statements. You only need that when you are writing C# code between HTML code. But when you are have started a C# code block, the ASP.NET MVC View Engine is intelligent enough to understand that the code that follows is C# and not simply some string.

Comment: can u help me to understand this thing giving small few sample code. thanks